# Friend function with default argument inside struct in C++

Tags: c++

I have a struct that looks like this:

```
struct Lip {
    int     x;

    friend Lip mkLip(Tester t, bool full = false);

    bool operator == (Lip p) const { return x == p.x; }
    bool operator != (Lip p) const { return x != p.x; }
    bool operator <  (Lip p) const { return x < p.x;  }
};
```

The problem with this is that it throws error on Mac regarding the friend declaration specifying a default argument. I read that one way is to have a non-friend declaration somewhere out, but as you can see my friend function has the same return type as the actual struct itself. What's the proper way to fix this here?

Comment: You can have a member function that returns `Lip`. If you want to make it a friend with a default argument, you'll need to define it inside the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your members are `public`, so you don't need a `friend` at all.

Just have a nice, normal function declaration:

```
struct Lip
{
    int x;

    bool operator==(Lip p) const { return x == p.x; }
    bool operator!=(Lip p) const { return x != p.x; }
    bool operator<(Lip p) const { return x < p.x; }
};

Lip mkLip(Tester t, bool full = false);
```

If you then introduce `private` members that the function needs access to, make it a factory in the form of a `static` member function:

```
struct Lip
{
  private:
    int x;

  public:
    static Lip mkLip(Tester t, bool full = false);
    
    bool operator==(Lip p) const { return x == p.x; }
    bool operator!=(Lip p) const { return x != p.x; }
    bool operator<(Lip p) const { return x < p.x; }
};
```

`static` member functions have access to private members of an instance (e.g. one that they create!).

---

You should also consider making the class's constructor `private` if it can't be safely constructed except when using `mkLip` to do so.

---

Note that introducing non-`static` `private` things to your class [will lose it its aggregate status](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50786105/4386278); you may or may not care.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed give it a definition inside the class:

```
friend Lip mkLip(Tester t, bool full = false) { return {}; }
```

However, this will affect name lookup on `mkLip`. Chances are you want `mkLip` to use normal lookup rules and lie outside of the class. In this case, you can always forward-declare the return type:

```
// Before class
struct Lip;
Lip mkLip(Tester t, bool full = false);

...

// Inside class
friend Lip mkLip(Tester t, bool full);

...

// After class
Lip mkLip(Tester t, bool full) { return {}; }
```

Comment: People (myself included) do tend to forget that return types can be incomplete, even though we write `void foo();` all the time ;)

Comment: I see the OP has upvoted and accepted already (within 30s!). Having a `friend` here is still completely pointless & unidiomatic, and makes the code way more complex to read than necessary. Though this is the right solution for someone locked into that decision.